# What is the object of a report on approval process?

Tags: reporting

I am trying to determine why a user cannot see a report.

I understand some things I need to check are:

- If the user has read access to the object
- If field level security hides any fields in the report from the user

However, I do not know what the object of this report is.

The report deals with approval requests. In the report editor, the heading above fields you can select is "Approval Request Info." As far as I can tell "Approval Request" is not an object.

**How can I determine what the object of this report is?**

Update after working with [gNerb's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/277830/61684):

- I created a report on the reports object to try to find out the type of the report in question. I found the report type, but I do not see that type in setup.
- I was also able to add "Object Name" to my report on the reports object. For the report in question, the object is "-".

Answer (score 0):

[You need to determine what report type the report is using](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000327673&type=1&mode=1) and you will be able to then view the config on the [report type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_builder_selecting_a_report_type.htm&type=5) to determine what object it is on.

Nearly everything in SF is an object and when you take custom objects into consideration, its not unreasonable to think there is an approval request object.

[You can generate a WSDL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickstart_get_WSDLs.htm) to get an idea of what all the objects in your org are. This will include both standard and custom as well as some hidden objects that are not easily seen in the UI.

In the WSDL use ctrl+f to perform a search for

```
<complexType name="OBJECTNAME">
```

Where object name is the api name of the object you are looking for, If you wanted to see if an approval request object is available, you could search for

```
<complexType name="Approval
```

This will find any object that starts with the word "approval"; then look through the results for an object close to what you are looking for.

In my org, the only standard approval object is

```
<complexType name="Approval">
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. When I create a report on the reports object, I see the report type, but I do not see that report type in setup. I also added "Object Name" to my report on reports, but for the report in question the object type is "-". I am not sure how to interpret this.

Comment: I checked in my bare bones dev org that I keep around and it does not appear to be a standard report or report type. Do you have a managed package installed related to approvals and or reports?